# JWT: what's the most secure (at today) of signature algorithms?

Tags: jwt

I'm reading https://jwt.io/ docs and found that actually supported algos are

- HS256
- HS384
- HS512
- RS256
- RS384
- RS512
- ES256
- ES384
- ES512
- PS256
- PS384
- PS512

**Which of this is the most secure?**

> I know that both parties (client and server) must use the same algo so it must be supported on both client and server sides.

Comment: You forgot to mention the EdDSA algorithm defined by https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8032.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The choice is really less about security and more about what you are using JWTs for - who can create/verify them, whether keys are shared, algorithm speed and so on. RSA and ES use public key cryptography so are used for situations where one trusted party creates a token which can be verified by others (but the others can't create tokens themselves). HMAC is much faster than RSA but requires that both the signer and verifier use the same key (which means they can both create tokens).

As a real example, [client authentication in OpenID](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#ClientAuthentication) can use a JWT which is HMAC signed using the secret key that the client and authorization server share. However HMAC would not be an appropriate algorithm for JWT tokens issued by the authorization server to represent things like client grants or ID tokens, since a malicious client application could then forge these tokens and impersonate the authorization server.

Algorithms using a larger hash are theoretically stronger (e.g. HS512 vs HS256) but in practice someone cracking the JWT algorithms in your system is unlikely to be a major concern compared with other security issues.

This is probably a better question for the crypto site, rather than SO and you should have a look there. See, for example [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/53826/hmac-sha256-vs-hmac-sha512-for-jwt-api-authentication) and [this one](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/30657/hmac-vs-ecdsa-for-jwt).

Comment: Thanks, larger hash is better than lower is a good point. Also, HMAC do not use private/public keys but a single key. I didn't know. Could I ask you which one use asymmetric keys?

Comment: Only HSxxx algorithms use a shared key. The other ones use either an RSA or EC key pair. Fully agree with this answer